# Mocha - Chai requires plugins globally

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai

I have followed *[How can I import the Chai 'expect()' function globally in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623260/how-can-import-chai-expect-function-globally-on-typescript)* to make the [Chai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#JavaScript) function *expect()* globally available in my TypeScript code.

How do I go on to make Chai plugins available to my [Mocha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mocha_(JavaScript_framework)) suite?

For example, the plugin `chai-arrays`.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are registered with the `use` function from `chai`. Using `chai-as-promised` for example:

```js
import { expect, use } from 'chai'
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised'

use(chaiAsPromised)

expect((async () => 'hello')()).to.eventually.equal('hello')
```

The key part of getting Chai available globally is the `--require` parameter passed to Mocha. It doesn't look like `chai-as-promised` exposes this kind of registration script, but it's trivial to write one yourself:

```
/// my-registration-script.js
require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'))
```

We can then call

`mocha -r ts-node/register -r chai/register-expect -r ./my-registration-script.js`

Bear in mind you may also have to set up your tooling as in [the referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623260/how-can-i-import-the-chai-expect-function-globally-in-typescript) in order to get your tooling to recognise that `chai` has been extended with the functionality provided by the plugin. While the brevity in test files not requiring explicit imports of `chai` and plugins is nice, it must be weighed against the added complexity of the toolchain.